# How to render JSON in Rails with JS function in field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, render

I want to give a response from the server like this:

```
{foo: "some value", bar: function(){console.log(this);}}
```

But if I write the response line in the controller like so:

```
render json: {foo: "some value", bar: 'function(){console.log(this);}'}
```

The result will be as follows:

```
{foo: "some value", bar:"function(){console.log(this);}"}
```

Comment: Results will be converted to String, you can remove `"` from the result.

Comment: I thought that there are ready tools for this. Or bar must be custom object, not simple string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use eval — it's unsafe and tricky. Wrap your function body with quotes, remove keyword function out of there and then create new function on the clientside with function constructor.

JSON:

```
{ 
   "fn": "alert(arguments);"
}
```

Clientside parsing code:

```
var myFunction = new Function(JSON.parse(jsonString).fn);
```

This is better because your function won't automatically execute any code or expose itself to the global context.

The only considerable inconvinience is the absence of arguments list. You have to use `arguments` object instead.

Comment: And furthermore: think about your application design a bit more. Maybe there's something wrong if you have to send functions to the client?

Answer (score 1):

use this on server side:

```
render json: {foo: "some value", bar: 'function(){console.log(this);}'}
```

Now you can post-process the parsed JSON:

```
json.bar = eval(json.bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

The server will always return you the value in string for your JS code part.

You can however the JS code using `eval` function.

like this:

```
eval(response.bar)
```

Given that:

```
response = {foo: "some value", bar:"function(){console.log(this);}"}
```